# Universal Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm working for some time on improving a plugin for Eclipse for C/C++. In the  IDE is is represented as an simple button inside the Tool Bar which  is used to start an user interface. To integrate the script inside the IDE you only have to copy the .jar files inside the  Eclipse/plugins folder.

At the moment I'm trying to make the plugin independent of the Eclipse IDE and it seems that I encounter some problems. I did the development in Eclipse Kepler and  tested the plugin on Eclipse Kepler, Luna and Mars. It seems to be working as expected on these versions. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for Eclipse Neon.I copy the .jar file inside the  plugin folder but  when  i run the IDE the button is not available inside tool bar as on the other versions.

Is there any constrain that I am missing? I already checked the dependencies of the  plugin.It requires only 3 additional  eclipse .jar files but those files are present inside the Eclipse/plugin folder.

Comment: Copying plugins to the Eclipse plugins directory is not a supported way to install plugins and hasn't been for a long time. You may be able to get it to work by specifying the `-clean` option when starting Eclipse.